# incompatible types when assigning to type 'double *' from type 'double' when trying to assign a pointer to a pointer

Tags: c, casting, signals, fft

I am trying to write the following algorithm:
[image: FFT algorithm]

This is my code:

```
double fft(int lenXH, int* X) {

    double wk;
    int j, p = 0, o = 0, k;
    double* e, * Xeven, * Xodd, * d, * Y;
    if (lenXH == 1) return X[0];
    Y = (double*)malloc((lenXH - 1) * sizeof(double));
    e = (double*)malloc((lenXH / 2 - 1) * sizeof(double));
    d = (double*)malloc((lenXH / 2 - 1) * sizeof(double));
    Xeven = (double*)malloc((lenXH / 2) * sizeof(double));
    Xodd = (double*)malloc((lenXH / 2) * sizeof(double));
    for (j = 0; j < lenXH; j++) {

        if (j % 2 == 0) Xeven[p++] = X[j];
        else Xodd[o++] = X[j];

    }
    e = fft(lenXH / 2, Xeven);
    d = fft(lenXH / 2, Xodd);

    for (k = 0; k < lenXH / 2 - 1; k++) {
        wk = pow(E, 2 * PI * I * k / lenXH);
        Y[k] = e[k] + wk * d[k];
        Y[k + lenXH / 2] = e[k] + wk * d[k];
    }

    return Y;
}
```

My problem is that I get the error "incompatible types when assigning to type 'double *' from type 'double'" . This is for

```
 e = fft(lenXH / 2, Xeven);
 d = fft(lenXH / 2, Xodd);
```

I have been stuck on this for some time so I thought maybe you could help. Please let me know if there are other mistakes. Thank you!

Comment: `double fft(int lenXH, int* X)` should be `double* fft(int lenXH, int* X)` - you are returning a pointer to an allocated array of `double`, not an individual `double` value. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Your function signature says it returns a `double`, while you expected a `double *`.

Change

```
double fft(int lenXH, int* X) { //....
```

to

```
double * fft(int lenXH, int* X) { //.....
```

After that, you need to take care of the statements

```
  if (lenXH == 1) return X[0];
```

where `X` is of type `int *`, so `X[0]` will be an `int`, which is neither compatible with `double` nor `double *`. Please make changes as necessary to return a `double *`.

Comment: You may have also missed the fact that fft parameter `X` is declared as `int *` ?

Comment: @PaulR Right, so `return X[0];` does not make sense. Let me update.

Comment: I suspect the function declaration needs to be changed to `double* fft(int lenXH, double* X)`

Comment: @PaulR but then also, `return X[0];` won't make sense. `X` has to be `double **` then. :)

Comment: Probably should be `return X;`, but the whole thing is a bit of a mess and the OP is unresponsive.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Would it be correct if in my main program X is of type int and in the function: double* fft(int lenXH, double* X) it is of type double? By that I mean, will the int pointer from the main program be promoted to double in the FFT function? I just changed it to "return X;" but I guess I'm still returning an int pointer to a double function. The idea is that in my main program I get X as an integer input, and then I have to calculate the output  using doubles. It's pretty confusing to me since it has pointer array, recurssion, type casting

Comment: @Udar: you should make the function take an array of double, since it's going to be called recursively. If you need to process int samples then convert the samples to an array of double in a separate function first.